# How do I remove spaces from a field input value when TAB is clicked on the screen on a HTML5 page using angularjs and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I remove spaces from a field input value when TAB is clicked on the screen on a HTML5 page using angularjs and Bootstrap

```
<input style="text-transform: uppercase;" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" ng-model="fieldInfo[' + $scope.idRow + '].FIELD_1" placeholder="Field 1" type="text" maxlength="30" ></td>
```

We tried couple of things but they do not work ... the idea is to have trailing spaces removed the moment user clicks on the tab button to move into the next field.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you:

```
    $('input').blur(function(e){
        $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
    })
```

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxgtz7vw/). Add spaces before and after your input and hit tab...

Comment: Thanks guys this one works fine with a static page but then I am building a dynamic HTML page in the Controller and hence this is not working there. The idea is to have a section where we can add rows dynamically and hence I build the rows in the controller, any pointers here would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$( ".form-control" ).change(function() {
   $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
});
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/t8htdeLc/1/

Comment: <script>
function myFunction(a) {

var x = document.getElementById(a);
x.value = x.value.trim();
}
</script>

Comment: I couldn't understand your comment.